# Why the print statement is not working in a function that return boolean?

Tags: python-3.x

may I ask why the print statement in the function below is not working? If there is something I have done wrong pls let me know.Thank you

```
def c_greater_than_d_plus_e(c ,d ,e):
    if c > d + e:
        return c > d + e
        print("c is greater than d plus e ")

print(c_greater_than_d_plus_e(3 ,1 ,1))

output: True
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you call `return` from a Python function, nothing after that will execute.  Try this version:

```py
def c_greater_than_d_plus_e(c ,d ,e):
    if c > d + e:
        print("c is greater than d plus e ")
        return c > d + e

print(c_greater_than_d_plus_e(3 ,1 ,1))
```

This prints:

```
c is greater than d plus e 
True
```